# Kendo UI multiple condition in template

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo UI Dropdownlist and I want to differentiate values in the dropdown based on condition.

1. if IsAssigned is 0 then style should be bold
2. After text = Unassigned style should be normal even IsAssigned is 0

This is the table text values I am binding with dropdown list :

```
text                                   IsAssigned
------------                            
EVP-RP&P                               0
Execution Coordinator                  1
Inspection Lead                        1
Instrument, Electrical, and Analyzer   0
Logistics                              1
Operations                             0
Planning                               0
------------               
Unassigned                             0
Abrams, Derek                          0
Abrams, Derek                          0
Administrator                          0
```

I am using the following condition in the template and It is working for condition 1 but I am not sure how I can stop applying bold style after text value = Unassigned

```
function loadPrimaryOwners(PrimaryOwners1, PrimaryOwners2) {
    $("#lstPOwner1").kendoDropDownList({
        dataSource: PrimaryOwners1,
        dataTextField: "text",
        dataValueField: "value",
        template: '<span style="#= IsAssigned ? "background:gray,font-color:white" : " font-weight:bold" #">#:text#</span>' ,
        change: function () {
            disablecontrol(this.value(), "#btnFilter1");
        }
    });
}
```

Please, can anyone help me with this issue?

Comment: Might be one of those change your data model and "IsAssigned" to be either -1, 0, 1

Comment: I'd put the decision making from the template into a separate function and call that one. This function could use a global variable which stores the information if "Unassigned" has been found or not. Depending on this information, you would make text bold or not. Btw. styles have to be separated with a semicolon: `background:gray;font-color:white`